# Fetching rows from a cursor PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-cursor

I have the cursor code:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE cliente_cursor 
CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM cliente;
```

I want to read all the content from the Table 'cliente':

[image: Table cliente]

With the use of a cursor. 
I have the code working for SQL Server:

```
DECLARE cliente_cursor CURSOR
      FOR SELECT * FROM cliente
OPEN cliente_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cliente_cursor;
While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
     FETCH NEXT FROM cliente_cursor;
End
CLOSE cliente_cursor
DEALLOCATE cliente_cursor
```

And I want to have a working code for PostgreSQL.

I have been looking for a solution & seen people usually suggest using functions. I wonder if there is any way in this PostgreSQL DBMS to create something similar to the code in SQL Server.

I had written this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyFunction()
RETURNS setof cliente AS $$
DECLARE 
cursor_cliente CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM cliente;
rec cliente%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
 OPEN cursor_cliente;
loop
--fetch the table row inside the loop
FETCH cursor_cliente INTO rec;
-- check if there is no record
   --exit from loop when record not found
   if not found then
        exit ;
   end if;
end loop;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But when I run it, I only get:

```
select MyFunction();
```

Any idea what should the code be instead?

[image: Results]

Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: I can't see how what you want differs from `SELECT * FROM cliente;`  it may be because I don't usderstand ms-sql-server

Comment: It is actually the same. With the difference I want the table to be shown through a cursor.

Comment: use a for loop then.

Comment: why do you want to use a cursor?  all it's going to do is slow the query down. inline plpgsql runs in a transaction same as plpgsql functions.

Comment: How  would I use the loop @Jasen ? Thanks for your answer.

I have to use cursors in PLPGSQL to do the same as the SQL server block of sentences

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS setof cliente 
   language plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  x cliente%rowtype ;
BEGIN 
  FOR x IN SELECT * FROM cliente loop
    RETURN NEXT x;
  END loop;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM foo();
```

it can also be done with an explicit cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo() RETURNS setof cliente
  language plpgsql as $$
DECLARE 
  x cliente%rowtype ;
  cliente_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM cliente; 
BEGIN
  FOR x IN cliente_cursor loop
    RETURN NEXT x;
  END loop;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM foo();
```

The function is going to persist so either give it a useful name and keep it around or drop it after you are done.

If you want a private name for the function  `pg_temp.foo` will be private to your session.

Comment: Awesome & clear explanation @Jasen. Thanks for your quick help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to return all rows from the query, use

```
RETURN QUERY
SELECT ...
```

and `RETURNS TABLE(column1 type1, column2 type2, ...)` as function's type.

Or for cursor:

```
RETURN QUERY
FETCH ALL FROM cliente_cursor;
```

---

To do something with each row, use

```
FOR _record IN
  SELECT ...
LOOP
  <action1>;
  <action2>;
  ...
END LOOP;
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28005997/7573844).

Or for cursor:

```
FOR _record IN
  FETCH ALL FROM ...
LOOP
  <action1>;
  <action2>;
  ...
END LOOP;
```

for cursor.

---

Note that PostgreSQL has `refcursor` type which allows you to use a cursor by it text name. IMHO it is simplest way ([read more](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html))